# Taking multiple screenshots during gameplay

Tags: pc, recording

How can I take multiple screenshots from a PC game during playing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The depends 100% on the game in question.

However, if your game doesn't natively support it, **[FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/)** is probably your best solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Xfire](http://www.xfire.com/) will take screen shots on almost every game it supports.

Comment: As will Steam, for that matter.

Comment: As will Raptr, for that matter.

Comment: Yeah but, at the time I answered this Steam could not.  I use it now instead of Xfire.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answer covers only the Windows PC operating system, here are a few more methods for other PC operating systems.

### Mac OS X

- Just press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to take a full screenshot.
- For an arbitrary selection press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> and then use the mouse to select what you want to capture.
- To capture a window use the same combo as before, then press <kbd>␣ Space</kbd> and then click on the window you want to capture. You may also do this to capture menus as well.
- You can also use `Preview` or `Grab` to get screenshots, as well as windows, selections and timed screenshots.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> and <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> also work in the classic Mac OS going as far back as at least System 6.
- All Mac screenshot functions play a camera shutter sound to inform the user that a screenshot has been taken (at least as far back as System 7).

Grab is one way to get screenshots and window captures:
[image: Grab on Mac OS X showing the Window Grab option]

The `File` menu in Preview also has a screenshot facility in the `Grab` submenu.
[image: Preview File menu hilighting "Grab"]

### Linux

This varies greatly by the flavor you install. Often there may be a utility simply called "Screenshot".

#### Ubuntu

- Press <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> will invoke the Screenshot utility and take a full screenshot.
- Pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> will take a screenshot of the current window.

[image: Ubuntu Screenshot utility.]