# Animated GIFs of the Machinarium robot dancing, and the officer with a teddy bear?

Tags: machinarium

I've been playing Machinarium, and the scene where the little robot dances to the band is never *not* adorable.  Also, the officer hugging his teddy bear, same thing.

I was wondering whether it was possible to obtain animated GIFs of either of the above to use as icons?

EDIT: Because I didn't make it clear initially, I'm not trying to make Windows icons from it; what I'm trying to do is use them as pictures akin to these: http://www.deadjournal.com/allpics.bml?user=mmaster

Comment: Does this question help? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384/taking-multiple-screenshots-during-gameplay

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is icons at the end of the day then follow the following steps:

1. download any screenshot utility. One example is [here](http://www.screenshot-utility.com/).
2. Create your own animated gifs to your hearts content using another utility. Again there are hundreds of options. One quick example is [here](http://www.gif-animator.com/). This is an ad supported version but at least you'll get access to the full functionality.
3. Now finally, you can create your own icon set totally customized to your liking using another tool. Again there are hundreds of free icon creaters out there. Here are a few examples: http://icofx.ro and http://www.free-icon-editor.com

Don't worry this whole process should not take more than an hour or two at most. At the end of the day you get exactly what you want and its more rewarding. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: ...By "icons", I mean "user pictures for my blog"...  (e.g. http://www.deadjournal.com/allpics.bml?user=mmaster) Which admittedly I didn't make clear.  I'm pretty sure I can't hit PrintScreen fast enough to capture an entire animation frame for frame.

Comment: Ah. Basically animated gifs has to be the end result. Also, I saw a video here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nqw98A-FtLc Is this the dance that you are looking for? And do you want the entire band or just the small silver robot part? (for what its worth I didn't downvote this. I find it extremely annoying when someone randomly downvotes stuff. +1 cause u provided more info).

Answer (score 1):

As for the robot dancing with the band, there is [an animated gif of that here](http://www.gifsoup.com/view/1589547/machinarium-robot-dance.html). You could get their "small" version, or just crop the part of the image you want using a [tool to crop animated gifs like online-image-editor.com](http://www.online-image-editor.com/). There are probably more of them out there. Just scour through imageblogs like [tumblr](http://www.tumblr.com/tagged/machinarium) or twitter. I found [this cutsey version of him dancing](http://verysweetmode.tumblr.com/post/15364780038/josef-for-all-the-fine-people-out-there) at tumblr for example.

You could always make animated gifs yourself with screenrecording software that outputs to images, but this will take some work. There has been a question related to that on [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/20381/is-there-a-screen-recording-app-that-saves-as-gif), this will probably have some caveats and bring its own set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wish to go the screenshot route, you may try a Flash decompiler/Flash resource extractor. You can use such a tool to directly extract the sprites used in the animation then use your favorite graphics editor to make an animated GIF version.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing screenshots, grab a [video of your gameplay](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/392/88)<sup>1</sup>, use a (free) video editing tool like [Avidemux](http://avidemux.berlios.de/) or [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/) to crop the selection and finally use something like [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) to [convert the video to a gif](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/video/).

<sup>1)</sup> The watermark of fraps might be somewhere not disturbing, I don't know. As bkzland [mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/45986/88), there is [a SU question](https://superuser.com/q/20381/35237) on this, but I don't know how well the solutions there work with fullscreen games (even if they're not 3D accelerated).